# End notes inside captions and equations

Tags: equations, captions, enotez

Page 2 of the [enotez package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enotez) documentation says that

> \endnote works fine inside tables, minipages, floats and captions.

However, *labelled* endnotes seem to cause a problem. Attempts to reference the figure end up with a reference to the note in the caption. Is there any workaround for this? As a bonus problem, is there a way to avert disaster if a labelled endnote appears in an equation (commented out in the MWE)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}
\label{sec}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy 
dog.\endnote[a]{Actually, the dog is dead.}\label{nt1}

The section: \ref{sec}
The note: \ref{nt1}

\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{4cm}
\caption{Here is some modern art{\endnote[b]{How much would you like to 
 pay for it?}\label{nt2}}}
\label{fig:modern_art}
\end{figure}
The figure: \ref{fig:modern_art}
The note: \ref{nt2}

%% \begin{equation}\label{eqn}                                                                                                               
%% A = B \endnote[c]{This is a really tricky equation}\label{nt3}                                                                            
%% \end{equation}                                                                                                                            
%% The equation number: \ref{eqn}                                                                                                            
%% The note: \ref{nt3}                                                                                                                       

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

[image: end note]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\label` macro uses values set in the last call to `\refstepcounter`.  In this case, the last call to `\refstepcounter` before `\label{fig:modern_art}` was made by `\endnote`, not `\caption`.

This solution uses a savebox to keep the two `\refstepcounter` `\label` pairs separate.

Since these values are set locally, it should be possible to use groups to keep them in order, but my experiments with groups so far have not worked.  In fact, it appears that `\endnote` is saving these values globally.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enotez}
\begin{document}
\section{This is a section}
\label{sec}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy 
dog.\endnote[a]{Actually, the dog is dead.}\label{nt1}

The section: \ref{sec}
The note: \ref{nt1}

\begin{figure}
\rule{4cm}{4cm}
\sbox0{Here is some modern art{\endnote[b]{How much would you like to 
 pay for it?}\label{nt2}}}%
\caption{\usebox0}
\label{fig:modern_art}
\end{figure}
The figure: \ref{fig:modern_art}
The note: \ref{nt2}

%% \begin{equation}\label{eqn}                                                                                                               
%% A = B \endnote[c]{This is a really tricky equation}\label{nt3}                                                                            
%% \end{equation}                                                                                                                            
%% The equation number: \ref{eqn}                                                                                                            
%% The note: \ref{nt3}                                                                                                                       

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

---

Another solution is to place the `\label` inside the caption in front of `\endnote`:

```
\caption{\label{fig:modern_art}Here is some modern art{\endnote[b]{How much would you like to 
 pay for it?}\label{nt2}}}
```

Comment: Interesting. I discovered the `\label` inside caption solution myself, but this didn't solve the problem with my actual document. Your `\sbox` solution did, so it saved me a lot of work in trying to create another MWE from a rather complicated docuent.